# How to call a class method "display" in such a situation

Tags: c++, winapi

I am making winapi app and I my code is structured like this. There is the MainClass and it has a few Child classes that display different controllers such as buttons and etc.
When I click on the button made by the Child class how can I call method "display()"?

```
class MainClass{
public:
 string currentWindow;
 Child1* Child1Win;
 Child2* Child2Win;
 void display(){
  clear();
  if(currentWindow == "child1"){
   Child1Win = new Child1Win();
   Child1Win->addControls();
  }
  if(currentWindow == "child2"){
   Child2Win = new Child2Win();
   Child2Win->addControls();
  }
 }
 void clear(){
  delete Child1Win;
  delete Child2Win;
 }
}

class Child1{
public:
 Child1(){}
 ~Child1(){ // cleaning }

 void addControls(){
  //setting up some controls
 }
 void someMethod(){
  // ! CALL HERE display() to change controllers
 }
}

class Child2{
public:
 Child2(){}
 ~Child2(){ // cleaning }

 void addControls(){
  //setting up some controls
 }
 void someMethod(){
  // ! CALL HERE display() to change controllers
 }
}
```

Comment: On which instance of `MainClass` do you want to call `display`?

Comment: What is `someVar`?

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3709485/how-will-contained-class-call-member-function-of-containing-class-composition) sounds similar, although it lacks a [mre].